# Get element detections before the inference tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

this week i'm "playing" with Tensorflow 2 and i try object detection and i dont know how to do the following:

In the tutorial TF2 object detection, get the inference of some elements in one image, as i show in the following code:

```
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
  input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
  input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
  detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
```

But i need to get the elements or regions detected, before the inference. I mean, the coordinates of the proposed regions but i dont know how to do that. I try to split the process, in one hand the region proposal and in the other hand the inference.

My code is the following:

```
def make_inference(image_path,counter,image_save):
  print('Running inference for {}... '.format(image_path), end='')
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
  input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
  input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
  detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
  num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
  detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                   for key, value in detections.items()} 
  detections['num_detections'] = num_detections
  detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)
  image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()
  viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np_with_detections,
        detections['detection_boxes'],
        detections['detection_classes'],
        detections['detection_scores'],
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        max_boxes_to_draw=200,
        min_score_thresh=.5,
        agnostic_mode=False)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
  nombre = str(counter)+'.jpg'
  plt.savefig('/content/RESULTADOS/'+nombre,  dpi=dpi ,bbox_inches='tight')
  counter = counter+1
  plt.clf()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `detections` dictionary contains the bounding boxes. I'm unsure what are you expecting as output. Can you show an example of the output you need? Your function looks like it will paint the bounding boxes of the image and save it under `/content`

Answer (score 0):

I worked as a software engineer and data science really requires a lot of OOPS implemented hence (however OOPS in Python is a Joke [IMO]), I have taken the liberty to draw out a class instead and have the following function to get a `List[DetectedObj]`

Simple POJO class to hold every detection you received.

```
from typing import Dict, Any, Optional, List
import numpy as np

class DetectedObject:
 
        def __init__(self, ymin: float, xmin: float, ymax: float, xmax: float, category: str, score: float):
               self.xmin = xmin
               self.ymin = ymin
               self.xmax = xmax
               self.ymax = ymax
               self.clazz = clazz
               self.score=score
```

Call the following function & pass your detections which you received from detect_fn

```
def get_objects_from_detections(detections: Dict[str, Optional[Any]], categories: Dict[int, Optional[Any]], threshold: float = 0.0) -> List[DetectedObject]: 
        det_objs = []
        bbox_list = detections['detection_boxes'].tolist()
        for i, clazz in np.ndenumerate(detections['detection_classes']):
            score = detections['detection_scores'][i]
            if score > threshold:
                clazz_cat = categories[clazz]['name']
                row = bbox_list[i[0]]
                tiny = DetectedObject(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], clazz_cat, score)
                det_objs .append(tiny)
        return det_objs
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the regions proposed by the model before do the inference for example in one image, i need to know all the proposed regions and print the coordinates before the inference, because for example i want to add some changes or add new regions manually and them get the inference

Comment: Can you elaborate on `coordinates before the inference` ? What coordinates are you looking for? Are you looking for this : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/generate_bounding_box_proposals

Comment: The function doesnt work. In detections = detect_fn(input_tensor) the model detect the elements and do the inference. I need to get the elements previously but i dont know how to do that

Comment: Can you elaborate on elements? the `input_tensor` is simply your image. The inference is working on top of the model you have loaded