# Get the region proposed by the model before predict with tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I try object detection with tensorflow 2 and i dont know how to do the following:

In the tutorial TF2 object detection, get the inference of some elements in one image, as i show in the following code:

```
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
  input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
  input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
  detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
```

But i need to get the elements or regions before the class inference. I need to access to al regions proposed to make some changes or insert new regions and then get the class of every one of them.

My code is the following:

```
def make_inference(image_path,counter,image_save):
  print('Running inference for {}... '.format(image_path), end='')
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
  input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
  input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
  detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
  num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
  detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                   for key, value in detections.items()} 
  detections['num_detections'] = num_detections
  detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)
  image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()
  viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np_with_detections,
        detections['detection_boxes'],
        detections['detection_classes'],
        detections['detection_scores'],
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        max_boxes_to_draw=200,
        min_score_thresh=.5,
        agnostic_mode=False)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
  nombre = str(counter)+'.jpg'
  plt.savefig('/content/RESULTADOS/'+nombre,  dpi=dpi ,bbox_inches='tight')
  counter = counter+1
  plt.clf()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get element detections before the inference tensorflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083328/get-element-detections-before-the-inference-tensorflow-2)

Comment: The answer cant solve my question, i need to get the region proposed by the model before predict the class on every one of them